# Blocking Tiktok Android app from router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android, domain, url

I was wondering how can I block the TikTok Android app from the router it self?

My router has a function to block a web address or an ip address.

So does anyone know what website/IP address should I block to make the TikTok App not able to connect?

Comment: I think TikTok uses the [Alibaba Cloud CDN](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/cdn), so if you try to block TikTok by IP, you'd block all the other sites that use that [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). (IP lookups: [`tiktok.com`](https://www.ip-adress.com/website/tiktok.com), [`sgali-mcs.byteoversea.com`](https://www.ip-adress.com/website/sgali-mcs.byteoversea.com))

Comment: @Deltik Is there any way to get the domains that TikTok uses in its apps?

Comment: @NAND: You could set up a packet capture at your gateway and check what DNS lookups happen as you use the app, but this approach wouldn't help if the app has hard-coded IPs or maybe uses [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS).  Or you could try to reverse-engineer the app, but I imagine that would be much harder to do.